# How to Plot integers against string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
Alphabet  Number  Vertical Horizontal  Theta  Phi  Yield  
    B      23      Top        Left       90   90   457.0   
    K      22      Middle     Middle     90   90   625.0   
    U      23      Top        Right      90   90   767.0   
    B      21      Top        Left        0    0   423.0   
    K      22      Bottom     Middle      0    0   547.0
```

I have set of values in the column yield to be plotted against columns Vertical and Horizontal as shown in above table. I have loaded all these data in pandas data frame. How to easily plot them against each?

Answer (score 0):

Yield is going to be the x-axis, vertical the y-axis [where: bottom = 0, middle = 1, top = 2] and we will use different markers for horizontal [`<`, `^`, `>`]

First I create the dataframe with the sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Vertical': ['Top', 'Middle', 'Top', 'Top', 'Bottom'],
                        'Horizontal': ['Left', 'Middle', 'Right', 'Left', 'Middle'],
                       'Yield': [457.0, 625.0, 767.0, 423.0, 547.0]})
```

We created 2 dictionaries that will help us later to plot:

```
map_vertical = {'Top': 2, 'Middle': 1, 'Bottom': 0}
map_horizontal = {'Left': '<', 'Middle': '^','Right': '>'}
```

And we plotted it:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    plt.plot(row.Yield, map_vertical[row.Vertical],
             marker=map_horizontal[row.Horizontal], color='b')
ytick = plt.yticks([0, 1, 2], ['Bottom', 'Middle', 'Top'])
plt.xlabel('Yield')
plt.ylabel('Vertical')
```

[image: So_example_plot_categorical_data]

The only thing missing is a legend that says which marker is each.